# Череп, черепаха, черепок (черепки) и черепица.  Что общего?

Tags: словообразование, этимология

Очень похожи слова: череп, черепаха, черепок (черепки, осколки глиняных сосудов) и черепица.  Что общего у них? Череп- - изначально общий корень? А сейчас?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так, собственно, форма. Кусок чего-то круглого. Посмотрите на форму всего, что Вы перечислили - все оно имеет сферическую форму и пустотело.
Мне кажется, тут в этом дело.

Answer (score 2):

Черпать  захватывать что-то .Черепки черпаки .

Answer (score 1):

> Так, собственно, форма. Кусок чего-то
> круглого. Посмотрите на форму всего,
> что Вы перечислили - все оно имеет
> сферическую форму и пустотело. Мне
> кажется, тут в этом дело.

Помимо формы, возможно их объединяет общее свойство твёрдости (кость, панцирь, глина).
сферичность + твёрдость